# Trying to Start Two Python Scripts with Cron at Startup

Tags: cron, python

I have put the following commands in the `crontab` file:

```
@reboot python3 /home/pi/rpi_camera_surveillance_system.py &
@reboot python3 /home/pi/KestrelPi/PIRkestrellogger.py &
```

The first script runs fine but the second does not.  I am providing both scripts below but I have also tested the second and it runs fine when called from the command line.

First Script:

```
# Web streaming example
# Source code from the official PiCamera package
# http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes2.html#web-streaming

import io
import picamera
import logging
import socketserver
from threading import Condition
from http import server

PAGE="""\
<html>
<head>
<title>Kestrel Camera</title>
</head>
<body>
<center><h1>Kestrel Cam</h1></center>
<center><img src="stream.mjpg" width="640" height="480"></center>
</body>
</html>
"""

class StreamingOutput(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.frame = None
        self.buffer = io.BytesIO()
        self.condition = Condition()

    def write(self, buf):
        if buf.startswith(b'\xff\xd8'):
            # New frame, copy the existing buffer's content and notify all
            # clients it's available
            self.buffer.truncate()
            with self.condition:
                self.frame = self.buffer.getvalue()
                self.condition.notify_all()
            self.buffer.seek(0)
        return self.buffer.write(buf)

class StreamingHandler(server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == '/':
            self.send_response(301)
            self.send_header('Location', '/index.html')
            self.end_headers()
        elif self.path == '/index.html':
            content = PAGE.encode('utf-8')
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
            self.send_header('Content-Length', len(content))
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(content)
        elif self.path == '/stream.mjpg':
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Age', 0)
            self.send_header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, private')
            self.send_header('Pragma', 'no-cache')
            self.send_header('Content-Type', 'multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=FRAME')
            self.end_headers()
            try:
                while True:
                    with output.condition:
                        output.condition.wait()
                        frame = output.frame
                    self.wfile.write(b'--FRAME\r\n')
                    self.send_header('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg')
                    self.send_header('Content-Length', len(frame))
                    self.end_headers()
                    self.wfile.write(frame)
                    self.wfile.write(b'\r\n')
            except Exception as e:
                logging.warning(
                    'Removed streaming client %s: %s',
                    self.client_address, str(e))
        else:
            self.send_error(404)
            self.end_headers()

class StreamingServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, server.HTTPServer):
    allow_reuse_address = True
    daemon_threads = True

with picamera.PiCamera(resolution='640x480', framerate=24) as camera:
    output = StreamingOutput()
    #Uncomment the next line to change your Pi's Camera rotation (in degrees)
    #camera.rotation = 90
    camera.start_recording(output, format='mjpeg')
    try:
        address = ('', 8000)
        server = StreamingServer(address, StreamingHandler)
        server.serve_forever()
    finally:
        camera.stop_recording()
```

Second Script:

```
# Log motion in Kestrel Box every five seconds in a csv file
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import datetime
import csv

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.IN)         #Read output from PIR motion sensor
GPIO.setup(3, GPIO.OUT)         #LED output pin

while True:
        i=GPIO.input(11)
        if i==0:                 #When output from motion sensor is LOW
                print ("No motion",i)
                GPIO.output(3, 0)  #Turn OFF LED
                time.sleep(5)
        elif i==1:               #When output from motion sensor is HIGH
                now = datetime.datetime.now()
                GPIO.output(3, 1)  #Turn ON LED
                with open('bird_log.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
                        logwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
                        logwriter.writerow([now.strftime("%Y")] + [now.strftime("%d")] + [now.strftime("%m")] + [now.strftime("%H")] + [now.strftime("%M")] + [now.strftime("%S")] + ["motion"])
                print ([now.strftime("%Y")] + [now.strftime("%d")] + [now.strftime("%m")] + [now.strftime("%H")] + [now.strftime("%M")] + [now.strftime("%S")] + [ "motion"])
                time.sleep(5)
```

I am just wondering how I can get the second script to run at start up in addition to the first.

Comment: Both scripts should run. Does maybe the second script need the first one to be up an running in order to start? In that case add some delay or check in the second script. Try to make some output from the second script and redirect it to file, to write some debugging information, which will help you find the error (`@reboot python3 /home/pi/KestrelPi/PIRkestrellogger.py > debuginfo.txt`). I also think you don't need `&` at the end of line.

Comment: i would suspect the `print` statements ... comment them out, or change them to some `debug log` command ... the first script has an example of it .... perhaps `logging.info()`

Comment: @nobody is correct.  I had been looking at the log file in the wrong directory.  Your debug file showed me that there was a log file in the same place.  Stupid mistake.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW:

When a script runs from the command line, but doesn't run under `cron`, the cause is generally due to `PATH` differences, or **resource timing** issues:

#### 1. `PATH` is different:

Your `cron` job **does not** run with the same **ENVIRONMENT** as commands issued from your interactive shell. `printenv` can show you the difference:

```bsh
$ printenv
...
PATH=/home/pi/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin: etc, etc 
...
```

Now, edit your `crontab` to create a `cron` job that runs `printenv` & redirects the output to a file:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/printenv > /home/pi/mycronenvironment.txt 2>&1
```

If you issue a command in your `crontab` that's *not* in its PATH, you can either: 1) change the PATH, or 2) use the full path to the command

#### 2. `cron` has no knowledge of resource availability

This crops up most often when a job is scheduled using the `@reboot` facility. For example, if your `cron` job starts at boot time, and requires network services. If the network is not yet available, your job will simply fail. And since it's not *interactive*, you won't see the output (`stdout` and/or `stderr`)  and any error messages or warnings may be lost.

The solution is often to add some `sleep` before running your command. For example:

```
@reboot /bin/sleep 20; /path/to/myscript >> /pi/home/myscriptlog.txt 2>&1
```

When `cron` is launched at boot time, and this line executes, `cron` will `sleep` for 20 seconds before running the next command. This almost always works, but of course is *imprecise* as we may not know with any certainty when the resources will become available. If your job requires it, or if this uncertainty bothers you, [you should consider `systemd`](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=systemd+start+script+at+boot&t=ffnt&ia=web); it maintains visibility of system resources during the boot process, and can start your job ASAP.

#### Also note: Error messages from jobs run under `cron` default to `/dev/null`

This issue is rectified as shown above: a *redirect* of `stderr` and `stdout` to a "log file":

```
>> /home/pi/cronjoboutput.log 2>&1
```